# Spring multi tenancy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I have two databases: `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL` where I have multiple schemas - one per each customer. I need to have an opportunity to route datasources by web request. I tried to use Spring's `AbstractRoutingDatasource` but it works only with single dialect. Are there any other solutions for this task?

Comment: Why do you need to have it in single application? Can't you have multiple applications configured each for its own database? And just choose needed one. Create repository and reuse it across all your apps.

Comment: **route datasources by web request** , do these web requests have different urls ? What I mean to say is - does service implementation classes different for different customers or you wish to initialize a single service service class with different data sources  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You can explicitly tell Hibernate which dialect to choose using `hibernate.dialect` property. So you can implement your own dialect extends `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` class, override all public methods and delegate calls to specific dialects. The good thing is Hibernate calls this (`Dialect`'s) methods before performing any database requests. In my specific case I've implemented a custom dialect with map of dialects I need for my project and now I can use the same repositories and  freely choose Postgresql, Oracle or MySQL depending on logged in user

Comment: Great solution and explanation, thanks a lot!